# Laravel backpack send variables to custom button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to create a customizable button that can be used in all controllers.

To achieve this I created an helper which contains a `addCustomButton` function. This function adds a `widget` containing the javascript the button is going to execute and calls the `addButtonFromView` function of the `CRUD` class.

What I need is to make a couple of variables available to the blade file so that, depending on what I need the button to do, I can pass a different content and action.

On SO, GitHub and documentation it's said that setting parameters on `$this->data` makes them available on the blades. So I tried to also pass the context, both by value and by reference, and to load it with the parameters I need before actually adding the button. Whatever I do, it says that those variables are undefined.

Definition:

```
 public static function addCustomButton(&$context, $config)
    {
        if (!isset($config['stack'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('[addCustomButton] Missing parameter: stack');
        }
        if (!isset($config['text'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('[addCustomButton] Missing parameter: text');
        }
        if (!isset($config['action'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('[addCustomButton] Missing parameter: action');
        }

        $action = $config['action'];

        $context->data['action'] = $action;
        $context->data['text']   = $config['text'];
        $context->data['icon']   = $config['icon'] ?? null;

        Widget::add()->type('script')->content("assets/js/admin/actions/$action.js");
        CRUD::addButtonFromView($config['stack'], 'custom', 'custom', $config['position'] ?? 'end');
    }
```

Usage:

```
CrudHelper::addCustomButton($this, [
            'stack'  => 'top',
            'text'   => 'back',
            'action' => 'goBack',
        ]);
```

First of all, is this advisable? I was trying to achieve this to have a custom template that I could use anywhere, since creating a custom button for every single thing I have to do feels unnecessarily repetitive. I'm not sure if this is a good or viable idea tho. Could this cause problems?

If it's safe, is it possible to achieve this result?

Comment: I think it is possible to transfer the data like this: `CRUD::addButtonFromView(...)->with(['action' => $action, 'text' => $config['text'], 'icon' => $config['icon']])`

Comment: @MahdiSamavi thanks, apparently `adButtonFromView` returns `null` though, resulting in the error `Call to a member function with() on null`. I've seen that it's still possible to access the `entry` variable, I might try to append my variables to it and access them like `$entry['myValue']`